# Slow query 80% of db time spent here

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi stackoverflow I have here a sql statement that is pretty slow performing which I think is due to the subquery seen in the sql below. My question is simply given that this subquery and the fact that it must set 'exists' to 0 or 1 given the logic can this be improved.

```
    SELECT
    p.id,
    p.name,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) > 0
        FROM
            product_log AS pl
        WHERE
            pl.product_id = p.id
            AND
            pl.state_name in ("Creation", "Auction", ...)
    ) AS 'has_log'
    from product as p;
```

Table creations for log and product

```
CREATE TABLE `product_log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
  KEY `state_name` (`state_name`,`create_datetime`)
(`id`,`product_id`,`state_name`,`create_datetime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8132540 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Running explain on the query, is a bit different since much of the details where omitted compared to the actual query that is run but here is the output

```
|id |select_type       |table|partitions|type  |possible_keys                                                    |key                |key_len|ref                          |rows  |filtered|Extra                                       |
|---|------------------|-----|----------|------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------|-------|-----------------------------|------|--------|--------------------------------------------|
|1  |PRIMARY           |p    |          |eq_ref|PRIMARY,guarantee_list_index                                     |PRIMARY            |4      |ppd.product_id               |1     |100     |                                            |
|2  |DEPENDENT SUBQUERY|pl   |          |ref   |product_id,state_name                                            |product_id         |5      |p.id                         |3     |51.5    |Using where                                 |
```

Comment: Can you include the `show create table product` and `show create table product_log` in your question.

Comment: how are your indexes defined? if you are using non-indexed fields in your query (my suspect is `product_log.state_name`) you may be doing full table scans

Comment: Have you created corresponding INDEX on product_log table?

Comment: run An EXPLAIN your query and also show us the indexes you have. i would make a index with id and state_name, which seem to me that your table is not normalized

Comment: On a side note: You have the quotes reversed. Single quotes are for string literals (like `'Creation'`); double quotes are for names (like `AS "has_log"`, and the quotes are even not need here, just make this `AS has_log`).

Comment: @danblack I have added DDL of product_log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to count all matches. Instead just check whether at least one match exists with `EXISTS` or `IN`.

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.name,
  EXISTS
  (
    SELECT null
    FROM product_log AS pl
    WHERE pl.product_id = p.id
    AND pl.state_name in ('Creation', 'Auction', ...)
  ) AS has_log
FROM product AS p;
```

or

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.name,
  p.id IN
  (
    SELECT pl.product_id
    FROM product_log AS pl
    WHERE pl.state_name in ('Creation', 'Auction', ...)
  ) AS has_log
FROM product AS p;
```

Both queries do the same thing, so the DBMS can can up with the same execution plan for both. But the queries show there are two ways the DBMS may approach the task:

1. Loop through all products and look up each product's logs.
2. Find all products with a requested log and use this list for the lookup.

These approaches require different indexes. If I want to lookup the logs for a product, I want:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON product_log (product_id, state_name);
```

If I want to build the lookup list first, I want:

```
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON product_log (state_name, product_id);
```

I suggest you create both indexes. Then see the explain plan for the query, see which one is used and drop the other.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your detailed answer.
I went with using EXISTS, however, currently we only have indexes for product_id and state_name independtly, this is not sufficient in this case I guess. 

The problem with our product state log in prod is huge so adding a new index might be tricky. Should simply using EXISTS with indepedent indexes also improve performance somewhat ?

Comment: Check the explain plan to see whether an index is used. This depends on whether the DBMS thinks using an index here is useful. This is usually the case when it is very selective. So if there are 10000 products and each has about the same amount of log entries, then the DBMS may use the index on product _id, as it expects just to have to read 0,01 % of the table rows. And yes, EXISTS should be faster than counting, because the DBMS can stop once it finds a match, rather than having to read all the other rows and count matches.

Answer (score 3):

something like?

```
select p.id, p.name, CASE WHEN pl.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS has_log
from product as p
left join product_log AS pl on pl.product_id = p.id AND pl.state_name in ("Creation", "Auction", ...)
```

eliminating the sub select executed each row,
and avoid using count() having to go over all records if you only need exists

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, however, we are not interested in a doing a join in this case.

Comment: Hi again This actually seems like the most simple solution, thanks